# When does the initialization of a const variable occur?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm wondering who actually calls the function and initialize the const variable?

This is in global scope of a .c file.

```
static const uint32 *GetTableAddress(void)
{
    if(memcmp(buf1, buf2, sizeof(buf1)) == 0)
    {
      return(&buf1);
    }
    else
    {
        return((uint32*)0x12345678);
    }
}

const uint32 *tab = GetTableAddress();
```

Comment: *"who actually calls the function"* - Can't you use some sort of find command to see where it is called? How do you expect us to tell you?

Comment: `const uint32 *tab = GetTableAddress();` this is not standard C. In standard C you cannot call a function to initialize a static variable. But in implementations where this is possible (I think gcc allows it), `GetTableAddress` is probably called by the same function that calls main. Use your debugger to find out.

Comment: That very much looks like C++, not C. And your question should rather be: When this function initializes variables, who initializes the global variables used by the function (`buf1`, `buf2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out what is happening is to compile it and look at the generated assembly.
Even if you're not so familiar with assembly you get some grasp of what's going on.

I just tried your code snippet in my ATmega328P testproject in Atmel Studio 7 with avr-g++ 5.4 and it produces some "function" named `<_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii>` which seems to be called before entering `main`. Last thing it does is calling

```
120:    0e 94 5f 00     call    0xbe    ; 0xbe <_ZL15GetTableAddressv>
```

which is your function.

As others have said, this is not standard C and that's just the way avr-g++ does it.

Comment: avr-g++ is not C at all.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that in your code, `const uint32 *tab = GetTableAddress();` actually exists in a function, because at file level, data initialization can only be done from compile time data (never a function).

In that case:

```
static const uint32 *GetTableAddress(void) { ... }
```

declares and defines a function returning a `const uint32_t *` pointer with internal linkage (`static` only denotes internal linkage for a function)

```
const uint32 *tab = GetTableAddress();
```

is an incorrect initialization of a `const uint32_t *` if it occurs at file level, and a simple initialization of an automatic `const uint32_t` if it occurs inside a function. In that case, the function will be called at run time at object creation time, that is at the beginning of the enclosing block.

Here, `const` is just a promise made to the compiler that the program will never try to change the value of a variable.

---

As per your comment, the initialization occurs at file level. This is not allowed in C but is correct C++ where a static variable may have dynamic initialization. In that case (C++) the initialization of file level static variables occurs before the first instruction from main is executed.

Comment: first, thanks for the reply.
second, the code is not inside a function but at the file level.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is specified, but in many implementations there is a function that runs just before `main()`, whose job is to set up the memory areas used by the program. This would include running code to do that kind of initialization.